# Multiplying acceleration to match speed multiplier to achieve constant time max speed reach

Tags: acceleration

If maximum/desired speed is multiplied by $n_v$, how many times does acceleration need to increase to read speed in the same amount of time?

For example, originally you reach speed $v$ in 1s with acceleration $a$. How much does $n_a$ have to be for you to reach $n_v * v$ also in 1s with acceleration $n_a * a$?

I thought it would be $n_a = \sqrt{n_v}$. But the results I'm getting seem wrong.

Why I need this? There's a fly-camera in an application that I'm working on that allows you to fly and spectate some 3D map. Currently, it reaches max speed instantly, which is inconvenient for smoothly zooming up and moving small distances. Because the max speed of camera may change by a multiplier, I need to change the acceleration accordingly so that the acceleration mechanic is consistent, time-wise.

There is no mass involved, I'm solely talking about change in speed per time.

Comment: In linear motion, with constant acceleration, $v=u+at$, so $n_a=n_v$ if $u=0. But you have a camera with a complicated 3D trajectory, and I don't see how a simple multiplier will be useful in that scenario.

Comment: @PM2Ring I had a camera with a 3D acceleration, but that turned out to be just annoying, so the acceleration and velocity are always forward and are applied on camera transformation after all calculations. With true 3D acceleration/velocity, the camera felt like driving ship in zero-G - cool but impractical. What is $u$ in your formula?

Comment: In that formula, $u$ is the initial velocity, i.e., the velocity at $t=0$. In general, $v=\int a\, dt$, which simplifies to the previous formula when acceleration is constant.